# set loop to open the following process on batch file scripting

Tags: windows, batch-file

in my batch script,

```
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq udp-receiver.exe" | find /i "udp-receiver.exe" > 2 || (start c:\udp-receiver.exe -f 1.zip --nosync --interface 00-00-ab-00-00-CD --portbase 989)
(start d:udp-receiver.exe -f 1.zip --nosync --interface 00-00-ab-00-00-CF --portbase 989)
```

to open 2 session for udp recieve. I am require to use a loop to reopen the either 2 seesion if it close. how do i write the loop in batch file?

Comment: ist it [goto](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html), you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
 find /i "udp-receiver.exe" > 2
```

is incorrect. `>` is a redirection operator (output of the "find" will be redirected to the file "2").

If you want to count the number of lines containing a string, then you need to apply the `/c` switch to the `find` command.

```
for /f %%a in ('
 tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq udp-receiver.exe" ^| find /i /c "udp-receiver.exe"'
 ) do if %%a gtr 2 (echo more than 2) else (echo 2 or fewer)
```

may give you the results you seek.